# How to pass parameters through CCCallFuncND in Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

How to pass the parameters through CCCallFuncND. I want to pass one int value.

my code is:

```
int val= 6;
CCCallFuncND.action(this, "jumpUpAnimation", val);
```

and the method is

```
public void jumpUpAnimation(int index) {
    System.out.println("index is =====>" + index);
}
```

But the method itself not calling.

When i call the method like this:

```
CCCallFunc.action(this, "jumpUpAnimation");  //Method call working fine.
CCCallFuncN.action(this, "jumpUpAnimation");  //Method call not working.
public void jumpUpAnimation() {
    System.out.println("called" );      
}
```

But i need the parameters by the CCCallFuncND. How can i call and how to write the method with parameters? Please help me.

Comment: hoping my post may help you

Answer (score 0):

Change argument as Object type

if you use following call function :

```
 CCCallFuncND.action(this, "hitCallback")


 // then your call back will be as mentioned below:

public void jumpUpAnimation(Object  sender) {
     // if you no need to send params use this call back
}
```

if you use following call function

```
CCCallFuncND.action(this, "hitCallback", sprite)
```

then you have to call as follows;

```
public void jumpUpAnimation(Object sender,Object data){
     int index = (Interger)data;
    System.out.println("index is =====>" + index);  
    }
```